# Tikz - Draw multiple same sized rectangles on a4paper

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams, calendar

I want to create an a4paper with 24 same sized rectangles with numbers in it. This is what I've acquired for now:

```
\documentclass{article}                      
\usepackage{tikz}                            
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=2mm]{geometry}    
\begin{document}                             
\pagestyle{empty}                                                                        
\begin{tikzpicture}                                        
 \draw (0, 0) rectangle node {1} (4, 2.5);  
 \draw (0, 10) rectangle node {2} (4, 2.5); 
\end{tikzpicture}                                                                        
\end{document}
```

I've already looked for examples online but everyone does it differently. Also there are like 10 different coordination systems where you could align the rectangles on. From what I understand the syntax for the draw-command is as follows:

`\draw (<X>,<Y>) <shape> node {<text} (<width>, <height>);`

But this doesn't work. Both rectangles are at different sizes. I've also tried to swap coords and size parameters in the draw-command, but this gives me also two nonidentical rectangles. I really like writing things with latex but using tikz has always left me frustrated and unsuccessful.

Comment: Welcome. You need `+(<width>, <height>)` for that to be relative to the previous coordinate. Otherwise `()` are almost always absolute positions.

Comment: Or you could just set the node dimensions, since nodes are rectangular by default. Note that `<shape>` in that syntax can be any shape you like so long as it's a rectangle.

Comment: I don't know if it's useful, but you could use `tabularx{cccc}` for example and add the same tikzpicture inside each cell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be like this? If so, below there's one way to do it.

[image: result]

Basic ideas:

- just place `\node`s, where you draw their shapes, specifying their minimum dimensions, where (0,0) is top left, placing into negative y-directions
- use self defined styles, `nd` in this case
- place them via two `\foreach` loops
- use some constant values to fill width and height of your a4paper
- use a self-defined counter `lp` to insert 1,2 ... 24 as text to the nodes, where `\thelp` outputs the counters content

Kindly notice the long Tikz path until the ending `;`

```
\foreach ... \foreach ... ;
```

Kindly notice its key-action is to draw a node, e.g. for `\j`=`\i`=1:

```
\node[nd] at (5.2,-5.35)  {5};
```

Code:

```
\documentclass{article}                      
\usepackage{tikz}                            
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=2mm]{geometry}

% ~~~ circumventing that Tikz doesn't add loop variables ~~~
\newcounter{lp}%    new counter, called lp
\setcounter{lp}{0}% initialize it

% ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
\begin{document}                             
 \pagestyle{empty}                                                                        
 \begin{tikzpicture}[% self-define your styles
    nd/.style={ draw,
                minimum width=4cm, 
                minimum height=2.5cm,
                font={\LARGE},},
    ]                                      
%   \draw (0, 0) rectangle node {1} (4, 2.5);  
%   \draw (0, 10) rectangle node {2} (4, 2.5); 
    
    \foreach \i in {0,1,2,3,4,5}
        \foreach \j in {1,2,3,4}
            \stepcounter{lp}%           increment it by 1
            \node[nd] at (\j*5.2,-\i*5.35)  {\thelp};
 \end{tikzpicture}                                                                        
\end{document}
```